# Splitting Array Based on Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array full of dynamic `<select>` field options, that I would like to be split into separate arrays based on a certain value within each "loop".

Basically, I'd like two arrays: one with the data associated with `[subfirmdetailtype_id] = 14`, and one with `[subfirmdetailtype] = 25`.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Open
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 14
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Closed
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 14
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Large Growth
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Large Blend
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Large Value
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Mid Growth
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Mid Blend
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Small Growth
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Small Blend
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Small Value
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => World Bond
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Multisector Bond
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Municipal Debt
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Heigh Yield Muni
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [Subfirmdetailoption] => Array
                (
                    [option] => Heigh Yield
                    [subfirmdetailtype_id] => 25
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It's nice to provide the output of your data, but instead, if you can build a script of input data such as $data[14]['Subformdetailoption']['option'] = 'Heigh Yield'; and so on and then show us exactly what you want, we might be able to give you some pointers

Comment: We usually need some real input data to build a script like this because its hard to come up with a valid script if we can't test it

Comment: can you guarantee every `$value` in your array is going to be an array?  If not, do an isset and/or is_array check between loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will group arrays the way you want:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($your_array as $array) {
  $new_array['subfirmdetailtype_id'][
     $array['Subfirmdetailoption']['subfirmdetailtype_id']
  ][] = $array['Subfirmdetailoption'];
}
```

Later you can access groups like this:

```
$new_array['subfirmdetailtype_id'][14];
$new_array['subfirmdetailtype_id'][15];
```

Or loop through these grouped arrays.

Comment: Getting a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /Users/jwg2s/Sites/fundvista/app/models/subfirmdetailoption.php on line 51

Comment: fixed my prototype code to match the exact structure of your array, sorry for confusion.

Comment: This is extremely close, how can I loop through so I can multiple arrays (i.e. the array that fills id = 14 and another array that fills id = 15?) In a dynamic fashion so I'm not specifically calling the number 14...

Comment: foreach ($new_array['subfirmdetailtype_id'] as $id => $group) { ... }

where $id is one of (14, 15 or something else) and a $group is an array of all arays with 'subfirmdetailtype_id' equal to particular ID

Comment: I almost follow that but get lost in what goes in the foreach statement... Thanks so much for your help by the way, I spent about 3 hours trying to research this last night trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through them? Like:

```
$allvalues = array();
foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $value) {
    $allvalues[$value['subfirmdetailtype_id']] = $value['option'];
}
```

Comment: This needs to be dynamic, these values will not always be the same. (e.g. not always subfirmdetailtype_id = 14.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$myarr = Array(
    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Open",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 14
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Closed",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 14
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Large Growth",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Large Blend",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Large Value",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Mid Growth",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Mid Blend",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Small Growth",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Small Blend",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Small Value",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "World Bond",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Multisector Bond",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Municipal Debt",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Heigh Yield Muni",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        ),

    Array
        (
            "Subfirmdetailoption" => Array
                (
                    "option" => "Heigh Yield",
                    "subfirmdetailtype_id" => 25
                )

        )

);

foreach($myarr as $elem){
    if ($elem["Subfirmdetailoption"]["subfirmdetailtype_id"] == 14) {
        $id14[] = $elem["Subfirmdetailoption"]["option"];
    }
    if ($elem["Subfirmdetailoption"]["subfirmdetailtype_id"] == 25) {
        $id25[] = $elem["Subfirmdetailoption"]["option"];
    }
}
print_r($id14);
print_r($id25);
?>
```

Comment: This is close, but I want the 14 and 25 to be grouped into an array each, necessary for a foreach function later.  Is that possible?

Comment: I don't understand could you give an example of your preferred output in a post edit.